# Get multiple src in using foreach

Tags: jquery, html

How to find image src only using `foreach`

```
<div data-vimeo-id="" class="lg-thumb-item test" style="width:100px; margin-right: 5px">
<img class="test" src="uploads/slider_img/negy.jpg">
</div>
<div data-vimeo-id="" class="lg-thumb-item test" style="width:100px; margin-right: 5px">
<img class="test" src="uploads/slider_img/negx.jpg">
</div>
<div data-vimeo-id="" class="lg-thumb-item test active" style="width:100px; margin-right: 5px">
<img class="test" src="uploads/slider_img/posz1.jpg">
</div>
<div data-vimeo-id="" class="lg-thumb-item test" style="width:100px; margin-right: 5px">
<img class="test" src="uploads/slider_img/the-eleventh-hour-1254186_1920 after.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.attr` function and specify which of the `<img>` attributes you want to get:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("img").each(function (i, e) {
      console.log($(e).attr("src"));
   });
});
```